# Wordpress divi website is showing homepage twice and homepage at bottom of each page

Tags: wordpress, divi

My website is using Wordpress, Divi and Divi Pixel. My homepage is showing twice, if you scroll down it repeats itself.
Also, it is showing at the bottom of every other page, even if I create a new page with a blank template, my homepage is still showing within that page! I can't get my head around it. The link to my site is https:// lgardenservices .co.uk

Any help would be much appreciated, I've searched the web and asked AI but I can't seem to find a solution, have tested with different settings too.

I have tried creating a new page with blank template, homepage still shown on this page..

I have tried changing the settings on Wordpress so another page is the homepage, then trashed the "offending" homepage, but that homepage is still showing on every page even after being deleted!

I have cleared my cache, and tried on mobile and computer, still the same issue..